# is my USB flash device dead?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have HP v155w 16 GB pendrive. My pendrive is getting detected under `devices and printers` section. I can see usb drive component there. But it is not getting mounted. I checked `disk management` and `diskpart -> list disk` and it is not getting listed. I am even tried HP USB format software, but in vain. Is it the dead end for my flash drive? or i still have some hope?

Comment: Try plug it in a different port

Comment: Try these things and add them to your post:
1a) Try a different drive in the same port (rules out port being broken)
1b) Try a different drive in the same port (rules out driver problems)
2) Try the flash drive in a different computer.

If other flash drives work but the v155w keeps failing then it is either the drive or the contents of the drive.  Try a diskpart clean on it (careful: select the right disk). (Only possible if you can select said disk, which *might* work on a different USB port).  Post the results using the [edit link](http://superuser.com/posts/987194/edit).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest ditching it. The data stored is often much more valuable than the pendrive, relying on a flaky pendrive is madness.

Yes, it might be that it got messed up and can be reformatted. Or it might be that the port/cable of the hub/... are bad, you should rule that out as the comment by @Hennes explains.

Answer (score -1):

I really thought one to my usb drives was dead when it did not mount on one machine. But the trick is trying a different port (or directly rather than a usb hub) or another machine - keep trying different machines if you need to get something off it. If it's not compatible with any usb port on your machine and you have no other use for it you may need to pass it onto to someone who can use it.

Comment: Passing on a USB that may be defective? No, thanks...

Comment: Ye guys are hard hard core with your -1s. Well my meaning of "who can use it." was to pass the usb stick onto to someone _whose machine it worked on_ as an alternative to another item in the landfill